# How to create a new buffer with ivy-switch-buffer that shares a substring with an existing buffer?

Tags: ido, ivy

Suppose I have a file opened called "analysis-evaluation.tex" and I'd like to create a new buffer called "eval".  When using Ido, I would press `C-j` to create a new buffer rather than switching to an existing buffer; does such a functionality exist with `ivy-switch-buffer` too?

Comment: You can also try setting `ivy-use-selectable-prompt` to `t`: `The prompt line can be selected by calling ‘ivy-previous-line’ when the first
regular candidate is selected.`

Comment: Thanks for the info, this was what I needed, because Doom Emacs uses that by default.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `C-M-j` which calls `ivy-immediate-done` to force the output to be exactly what you typed instead of having it complete to the the nearest match

This and more information can be found in the ivy manual [ivy-manual](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer)