# How do I prevent autocompletion when trying to save a file?

Tags: ivy

I have an existing directory called `~/app_scripts` and a buffer open with a file I would like to save. I want to save it to `~/scripts/script.py`, but the `~/scripts` dir does not yet exist. When I hit `C-x C-s` to save, I try to type `~/scripts/` but it keeps autocompleting to `~/app_scripts`. How do I make it stop over-autocorrecting and let me choose a file name?
I cannot use `C-M-j` because that will immediately save the file at `~/scripts` (with no filename), instead of allowing me to continue to type the path I want.

Note: I'm not sure if this problem is Ivy-related or not, but I think it might be relevant to the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`)? See https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/wiki/FAQ#how-to-select-the-current-input-instead-of-the-current-candidate and [`(ivy) Key bindings for single selection action then exit minibuffer`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer).

Comment: See also [how to rename a file in neotree without ivy select confusing?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/39475/15748) and [How to create a new buffer with ivy-switch-buffer that shares a substring with an existing buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/21028/15748).

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot use `C-M-j` because that will immediately save the file at `~/scripts` (with no filename), instead of allowing me to continue to type the path I want.

Both vanilla Emacs and Ivy let you save to non-existing files within non-existing directories by specifying literal <kbd>/</kbd>-delimited file names without completion.

The problem in this case is that Ivy interprets <kbd>/</kbd> specially by default. Namely, typing <kbd>/</kbd> during Ivy file name completion will descend into the currently selected directory candidate, if one exists.

Thankfully, Ivy provides a user option to control this behaviour:

```
ivy-magic-slash-non-match-action is a variable defined in ‘ivy.el’.
Its value is ‘ivy-magic-slash-non-match-cd-selected’

Documentation:
Action to take when a slash is added to the end of a non existing directory.
Possible choices are ’ivy-magic-slash-non-match-cd-selected,
’ivy-magic-slash-non-match-create, or nil

You can customize this variable.
```

The default, `ivy-magic-slash-non-match-cd-selected`, will descend into the currently selected directory candidate, as mentioned above. `ivy-magic-slash-non-match-create` will, upon typing <kbd>/</kbd>, create a directory with a name corresponding to the current minibuffer input. `nil` is like vanilla Emacs in that it does not handle <kbd>/</kbd> specially.

So, for example, you can:

```el
(setq ivy-magic-slash-non-match-action nil)
```

followed by <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>`~/scripts/script.py`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>.

> I'm not sure if this problem is Ivy-related or not

It is, as you can confirm by disabling `ivy-mode`.

---

See also https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1532.